# What does subscribing an event to another event in C# do?

Tags: c#, events

I recently stumbled again on an issue regarding events and I couldn't find anything that answers what this syntax actually does: `event1 += event2`

Here are 2 example methods with the same events for testing purposes:

```
private event Action A = null;
private event Action B = null;
private event Action C = null;
```

This version (simplified) does work (which I used, with each event having its own Trigger-method):

```
private void DoTest1 ()
{
    A += () => DebugText ($"A Test");
    A += () => B.Invoke ();
    B += () => DebugText ($"B Test");
    B += () => C.Invoke ();
    C += () => DebugText ($"C Test");

    A.Invoke ();
    // Result: A Test, B Test, C Test
}
```

This does not work as expected:

```
private void DoTest2 ()
{
    A += () => DebugText ($"A Test");
    A += B;
    B += () => DebugText ($"B Test");
    B += C;
    C += () => DebugText ($"C Test");

    A.Invoke ();
    // Result: A Test
}
```

So I wonder, why does the compiler accept the syntax if it does not seem to work? What am I missing here?

Comment: Debug DoTest2 and see if B isn't null when it's added to A?

Comment: I think they are resolved at build time. Check [this order](https://dotnetfiddle.net/G1mN0p) and then, [this one](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vd2drF)

Comment: @Cid - I think I understand now, thank you! That's because this way events are just adding up their current content, rather than link them together in any persistent way. I remember that I learned about that ages ago, but I forgot this part. Btw, neat website!

Comment: Suppose instead of events and delegates you had `int A = 1; int B = 10;`.   If you say `A = A + B; B = B + 10; Console.WriteLine(A);` what do you expect to have written out? (1) `11` because `A + B` was 11 at the time of the assignment, or (2) `21` because at the time that the *WriteLine* happens, `A` somehow knows that `B` has become 20? Which do you expect to happen?